# Insert Same data to multiple databases using spring controller and jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to write a simple application to write some values to DB.

Basically this is some repetitive task which has to be done quite often and I want to build a simple Spring boot app with a UI exposed so that it can be done in an automatic way.

I have an Entity Class with a simple POJO MyClient and I have written a Controller and Service Classes and am able to GET and POST To DB:

My App.properties looks like below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@db-host-1:1521/xxx.xx.intern
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

//Controller Class

```
@GetMapping("/clients")
public List<MyClient> retrieveAllClientVersions(){
        return myClientService.listAllClientVersions();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/client/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    void addNewClientVersion(@RequestBody MyClient myClient){
        myClientService.addNewClientVersion(myClient);
}
```

//Service Class

```
private MyClientRepository myClientRepository;

@Autowired
public MyClientService(MyClientRepository myClientRepository){
        this.myClientRepository=myClientRepository;
}

public List<MyClient> listAllClientVersions(){
        List<MyClient> myClients=new ArrayList<>();
        myClientRepository.findAll().forEach(myClients::add);
        return myClients;
}

public void addNewClientVersion(MyClient myClient){
        myClient.setReleaseKeyVersion(RELEASE_KEY_VERSION);
        myClient.setClientVersion(myClient.getClientVersion());
        myClient.setDescription(DESCRIPTION);
        myClient.setReleaseCertDn(DGV_RELEASE_CERT_DN);
        myClient.setStatus(STATUS);
        myClient.setClientSecurityProfileDbId(CLIENT_SECURITY_PROFILE_DB_ID);
        myClient.setIssuerDbId(ISSUER_DB_ID);
        myClientRepository.save(myClient);
}
```

We have around 50 test environments where I need to run the same query. I wanted to create a UI where I can have check boxes against all environment with buttons like GET and POST.

Whatever environment user selects from check boxes and say POST the "Insert" should run on all those environments.

How can this be handled? Is there a way that based on Query Parameter in POST Request the Insert can be run on different DB. How do we connect to different DB at runtime? What could be best way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using these `checkboxes` inside a form and POSTing them (checkboxes and content) in a single request body?

Comment: I have not yet designed the UI. Right now I was working on BE. I am able to connect to DB & get the results from table and post a new record also to the same table. The DB connection is in the properties file.

 would like to know if there is an option to pass some parameters at Controller level & then at Service Level I can have a kind of switch & run the query on particular DB as per the matching param from the controller. 
Or Can I have different end points for POST to run the query on different DB"s 

Not sure what is the best way here, but how do I connect to different DB?